# Can I loop or rewrite the code for populating this list somehow?

Tags: javascript

I don't even know where to start?!? A hint would be much appreciated!

**JS:**

```
document.getElementById('first').getElementsByTagName('h3')(0).innerHTML = data.products[0].product;
document.getElementById('second').getElementsByTagName('h3')(0).innerHTML = data.products[1].product;
document.getElementById('third').getElementsByTagName('h3')(0).innerHTML = data.products[2].product;

document.getElementById('first').getElementsByTagName('p')(0).innerHTML = data.products[0].description;
document.getElementById('second').getElementsByTagName('p')(0).innerHTML = data.products[1].description;
document.getElementById('third').getElementsByTagName('p')(0).innerHTML = data.products[2].description;

document.getElementById('first').getElementsByTagName('h3')(0).setAttribute('class', data.products[0].code);
document.getElementById('second').getElementsByTagName('h3')(0).setAttribute('class', data.products[1].code);
document.getElementById('third').getElementsByTagName('h3')(0).setAttribute('class', data.products[2].code);

document.getElementById('first').setAttribute('code', data.products[0].code);
document.getElementById('second').setAttribute('code', data.products[1].code);
document.getElementById('third').setAttribute('code', data.products[2].code);
```

**HTML:**

```
<div class="items">
<ul>
<li id="first"><h3></h3><span><p></p><br><button>Find</button></span></li>
<li id="second"><h3></h3><span><p></p><br><button>Find</button></span></li>
<li id="third"><h3></h3><span><p></p><br><button>Find</button></span></li>
</ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Are you interested in using jQuery? It makes things like this much easier.

Comment: Yeah, normally I'd use jQuery, but I'm developing a tiny mobile app and I'm having a go writing it in plain JS..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try the following javascript:

```
var ids = ['first', 'second', 'third'];
for (var i = 0; i < ids.length; i++) {
    var product = data.products[i];
    var element = document.getElementById(ids[i]);

    element.getElementsByTagName('h3')[0].innerHTML = product.product;
    element.getElementsByTagName('p')[0].innerHTML = product.description;
    element.getElementsByTagName('h3')[0].setAttribute('class', product.code);
    element.setAttribute('code', product.code);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
var element, index, len, ids, product, header;

ids = ['first', 'second', 'third'];
for (index = 0, len = ids.length; index < len; index++) {
  element = document.getElementById(ids[index]), product = data.products[index],
  header = element.getElementsByTagName('h3')[0];

  header.innerHTML = product.product;
  element.getElementsByTagName('p')[0].innerHTML = product.description;
  header.setAttribute('class', product.code);
  element.setAttribute('code', product.code);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

As a rule of thumb use loops to carry out any repetitive work, and if you find yourself using one of the document.get... methods with exactly the same parameters more than once store the result in a variable for later use

```
var ids = "first,second,third".split(",");
var el, h3;
for (var i = 0, il = ids.length; i<il;i++) {
    el = document.getElementById(ids[i]);
    h3 = el.getElementsByTagName('h3')[0];
    h3.innerHTML = data.products[i].product;
    el.getElementsByTagName('p')[0].innerHTML = data.products[i].description;
    h3.setAttribute('class', data.products[i].code);
    el.setAttribute('code', data.products[i].code);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use Associative Arrays.

```
var arr = new Array("first","second","third");
for(var i in arr) {
    //Now, i has the value first in first iteration & similarly ...
        //Do you assignments here using i
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**getElementsByTagName** returns an **array**, in javascript **[]** denotes and array element:
Instead of this:

```
document.getElementById('first').getElementsByTagName('h3')(0).innerHTML = data.products[0].product;
```

use:

```
document.getElementById('first').getElementsByTagName('h3')[0].innerHTML = data.products[0].product;
```

That should do it!!!